# Pymongo check user permissions on connection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I enabled authentication on my MongoDB database, and I'm connecting to it through
pymongo. Everything works well when the user connecting to the DB has all the relevant permissions, but when a user with limited permissions connects, an exception is raised only when executing the first command.
Is there a way I can check the user's permissions on connection?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recent version of pymongo you may want to check this [page of the docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/migrate-to-pymongo3.html#mongoclient-connects-asynchronously)

> In PyMongo 3, the MongoClient constructor no longer blocks while
>   connecting to the server or servers, and it no longer raises
>   ConnectionFailure if they are unavailable, nor ConfigurationError if
>   the user’s credentials are wrong. Instead, the constructor returns
>   immediately and launches the connection process on background threads.
>   The connect option is added to control whether these threads are
>   started immediately, or when the client is first used.

They also provide a 'workaround' if you want to know directly whether the connection was successfully established with this

```
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure
client = MongoClient(connect=False)
try:
    result = client.admin.command("ismaster")
except ConnectionFailure:
    print("Server not available")
```

The reason for using the above `client.admin.command("ismaster")` is due to the fact that no special permissions are need to execute it

> Any operation can be used to determine if the server is available. We
>   choose the “ismaster” command here because it is cheap and does not
>   require auth, so it is a simple way to check whether the server is
>   available.